# crash when adding mapkit view in viewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm creating a viewcontroller with a mapkit view inside, on iPad i'm having some problem with a crash, i'm having this exception message:

```
[UIToolbar backdropView:willChangeToGraphicsQuality:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x175ba4b0
```

i've not added any toolbar so i don't know which deallocated toolbar is calling this method.
I've this problem only if i add to the view the mapview, and only in phisical device running ios7 and not in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have Zombie object. I can not say what to do without having code. But you can try to debug your code. You can see [this quick tutorial](http://iphone4developer.blogspot.com/2012/07/debugging-in-xcode-4x.html) to find Zombie objects